# Eclipse Breakpoint Propertes

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, method-call

In Eclipse, is there a way to toggle breakpoints ON at all the locations of a method call?

For example, I want to add breakpoints at all places where setVisible(boolean) is called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember, you can add a breakpoint at the beginning of the target function.

Comment: yes, but i am actually not sure which among many method calls (at different places in the project) is responsible for setting a property visible.

Comment: Place a breakpoint inside `setVisible`.

Comment: Thank you, I get that. but in my case there are around 20-30 declarations of this method in different projects/classes altogether as a product. Is there any other way than placing breakpoint at the start of all those declarations.

Comment: There's no wildcard, so no. Consider use search and place one by one.

Comment: okay. Thank you :)